# Cannot use In-Memory option, cannot open "Memory Optimization Advisor" in AZURE SQL DB version 12

Tags: sql-server, azure, in-memory-database, in-memory

I just open new DB on an old server in AZURE.
When trying to run the "Memory Optimization Advisor" I receive the following messege,

> Operation not supported on version 12.0.703 SqlAzureDatabase. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum)

When execute the following line

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'IsXTPSupported')
```

I receive 1.

Also the option to get reports on the new DB is grayed-out.

Comment: what pricing tier are you on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SSMS (SQL Server Managment studio) is not support thous features in 2014 version.

Possible to download the newset version from 
[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)